# Validation accuracy is better than training accuracy

Tags: neural-networks

What does it imply if, in the case of a neural network, validation accuracy is better than training accuracy?

Does this mean that the data set has issues or training has issues?

Can you elaborate?

Comment: there's a few things that could be going on here:

1: How did you do your train-eval split, was it random?
2: How big is the difference, how large is your eval set? Are you sure this difference is statistically significant?